# Validation error when making POST Boldsign API request

Tags: php, api, rest, http, curl

I hope you are all doing well.

I am trying to send a curl post request to the BoldSign API using their Send Document method (https://developers.boldsign.com/documents/send-document/). I have gotten the script to operate as intended when I hardcode the Signers Name or EmailAddress element as a string.
The code breaks and I get a 400 bad request status code response when I try passing the required elements as a variable.

I have tried passing the variable without quotes, with single quotes, with double quotes and appended onto the end of an empty single quotes string.
I thought that I may be having an issue with the formatting of post variables so I tried capturing the output of echo commands and print_r within an additional variable and passing that whilst trying the above variations.
Unfortunately all attempts are resulting in an error. I will attach my full code snippet and the HTML form below. Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

This is the error code I am getting:

```json
{
    "errors": {
        "Signers[0].Name": [
            "The Name field is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-c4ebfc6a234153afba810315e2f4b37a-00373d37127c3c0b-00"
}

400
```

p.s the values being passed in the html form are formidable forms shortcodes containing the values of form fields.

HTML Form Code

```
    <form action="/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/send-document-short.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        staff name:
            <input type="text" id="staffName" name="staffName" value="[7394]"><br>
        staff email
            <input type="text" id="staffEmail" name="staffEmail" value="[7397]"><br>
        client name:
            <input type="text" id="clientName" name="clientName" value="[7396]"><br>
        client email
            <input type="text" id="clientEmail" name="clientEmail" value="[7398]" ><br>
        Select pdf to upload:
            <input type="file" name="contractFile" id="contractFile" required><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send File" name="submit">
    </form>
```

PHP Script Code

```
<?php

    if ($_FILES['contractFile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("File upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['contractFile']['error']);
    }

    print_r($_FILES[contractFile]);
    $staffName = $_POST['staffName'];
    $staffEmail = $_POST['staffEmail'];
    $clientName = $_POST['clientName'];
    $clientEmail = $_POST['clientEmail'];
    $file = $_FILES['contractFile'];

    $sName = print_r($staffName);
    $sEmail = print_r($staffEmail);
    $cName = print_r($clientName);
    $cEmail = print_r($clientEmail);

    runSend($file);

    function runSend($file){

        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.boldsign.com/v1/document/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        
        $post = array(
            'DisableExpiryAlert' => 'false',
            'ReminderSettings.ReminderDays' => '5',
            'BrandId' => '',
            'ReminderSettings.ReminderCount' => '3',
            'EnableReassign' => 'false',
            'Message' => '',
            'Signers[0][Name]' => $cName,
            'Signers[0][EmailAddress]' => 'felix@email.com.au',
            'Signers[0][SignerOrder]' => '0',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][name]' => 'initial00',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][pageNumber]' => '3',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][IsRequired]' => 'true',
            

            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][Name]' => 'initial01',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][PageNumber]' => '4',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][1][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][Name]' => 'initial02',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][PageNumber]' => '5',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][2][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][Name]' => 'initial03',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][PageNumber]' => '6',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][3][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][Name]' => 'initial04',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][PageNumber]' => '7',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][4][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][Name]' => 'initial05',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][PageNumber]' => '8',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][5][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][Name]' => 'initial06',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][PageNumber]' => '9',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][6][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][Name]' => 'initial07',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][PageNumber]' => '10',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][7][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][Name]' => 'initial08',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][PageNumber]' => '11',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][8][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][Name]' => 'initial09',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][PageNumber]' => '12',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][9][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][Name]' => 'initial010',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][PageNumber]' => '13',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][10][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][Type]' => 'Initial',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][Name]' => 'initial011',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][PageNumber]' => '14',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][Bounds][X]' => '690',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][Bounds][Y]' => '1065',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][Bounds][Width]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][11][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][Type]' => 'Signature',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][Name]' => 'signature00',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][PageNumber]' => '8',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][Bounds][X]' => '80',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][Bounds][Y]' => '760',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][Bounds][Width]' => '205',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][12][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][Type]' => 'DateSigned',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][Name]' => 'datesign00',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][PageNumber]' => '8',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][Bounds][X]' => '390',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][Bounds][Y]' => '760',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][Bounds][Width]' => '150',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][13][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][Type]' => 'Signature',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][Name]' => 'signature01',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][PageNumber]' => '12',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][Bounds][X]' => '370',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][Bounds][Y]' => '820',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][Bounds][Width]' => '180',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][14][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][Type]' => 'DateSigned',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][Name]' => 'datesign01',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][PageNumber]' => '12',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][Bounds][X]' => '600',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][Bounds][Y]' => '820',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][Bounds][Width]' => '120',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][Bounds][Height]' => '25',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][15][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[1][Name]' => 'Alexander Name',
            'Signers[1][EmailAddress]' => 'alexander@email.com.au',
            'Signers[1][SignerOrder]' => '0',

            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][Type]' => 'Signature',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][Name]' => 'signature10',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][PageNumber]' => '8',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][Bounds][X]' => '90',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][Bounds][Y]' => '832',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][Bounds][Width]' => '200',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][Bounds][Height]' => '20',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][0][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][Type]' => 'DateSigned',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][Name]' => 'datesign10',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][PageNumber]' => '8',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][Bounds][X]' => '390',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][Bounds][Y]' => '832',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][Bounds][Width]' => '100',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][Bounds][Height]' => '30',
            'Signers[1][FormFields][1][IsRequired]' => 'true',

            'ExpiryDays' => '30',
            'EnablePrintAndSign' => 'false',
            'AutoDetectFields' => 'false',
            'OnBehalfOf' => '',
            'EnableSigningOrder' => 'false',
            'UseTextTags' => 'true',
            'SendLinkValidTill' => '',
            'Files' => new CURLFILE($file['tmp_name'], $file['type'], $file['name']),
            'Title' => 'testing',
            'HideDocumentId' => 'false',
            'EnableEmbeddedSigning' => 'false',
            'ExpiryDateType' => 'Days',
            'ReminderSettings.EnableAutoReminder' => 'true',
            'ExpiryValue' => '60',
            'DisableEmails' => 'false'
        );
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'X-API-Key: APRETENDAPIKEY4124234';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        
        echo $result;
        
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo $httpcode;
        
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);

    };
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `print_r` in `$cName` assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Variable Scope Issue

PHP is a [local variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) language. The variable `$cName` is not accessible within your function `runSend()` and therefore consider `NULL` in value. That would make `Signers[0].Name` either `NULL` or an empty string when submitted. Hence the error.

The simplest fix is to pass the variables, by value, into the function:

```php
runSend($file, $sName, $sEmail, $cName, $cEmail);

function runSend($file, $sName, $sEmail, $cName, $cEmail){
    // ...
}
```

### Usage: print_r

Also, why use `print_r()` for string assignment? `print_r()` only returns boolean `true` unless you set the second flag (`$return`). Try these:

```php
var_dump(print_r('hello'));
var_dump(print_r('hello', true));
```

Result:

```
hellobool(true)
string(5) "hello"
```

I guess you want the second one, right? But why bother with `print_r()` while you can simply do:

```php
$sName = $staffName;
$sEmail = $staffEmail;
$cName = $clientName;
$cEmail = $clientEmail;
```

or even

```php
runSend($file, $staffName, $staffEmail, $clientName, $clientEmail);

function runSend($file, $sName, $sEmail, $cName, $cEmail){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Such a silly mistake on my behalf. I actually figured this out on my own once I put the code within an IDE and saw that the variable was considered locally assigned. Completely forgot to pass them to the function. Thank you so much for your prompt and detailed response. You are a champion!